# parsing id from text with python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have this text:

```
>gi|124486857|ref|NP_001074751.1| inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase [Mus musculus] >gi|341941060|sp|Q6ZPR6.3|IBTK_MOUSE RecName: Full=Inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase; Short=IBtk >gi|148694536|gb|EDL26483.1| mCG128548, isoform CRA_d [Mus musculus] >gi|223460980|gb|AAI37799.1| Ibtk protein [Mus musculus]
```

From this text I want to parse the ID that comes after |gb| and write it in a list.

I try to use regular expressions but haven't been able to do it successfully.

Comment: Are the `>` characters part of the text?

Comment: something along the lines of \|gb\|(<id>.*?\|)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex should work

```
import re
re.findall('gb\|([^\|]*)\|', 'gb|AB1234|')
```

Answer (score 3):

Split on the `|` pipe, then skip everything until the first `gb`; the next element is the ID:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

text = iter(text.split('|'))
next(dropwhile(lambda s: s != 'gb', text))
id = next(text)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> text = '>gi|124486857|ref|NP_001074751.1| inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase [Mus musculus] >gi|341941060|sp|Q6ZPR6.3|IBTK_MOUSE RecName: Full=Inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase; Short=IBtk >gi|148694536|gb|EDL26483.1| mCG128548, isoform CRA_d [Mus musculus] >gi|223460980|gb|AAI37799.1| Ibtk protein [Mus musculus]'
>>> text = iter(text.split('|'))
>>> next(dropwhile(lambda s: s != 'gb', text))
'gb'
>>> id = next(text)
>>> id
'EDL26483.1'
```

In other words, there is no need for a regular expression.

Making this into a generator method to get all ids:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def extract_ids(text):
    text = iter(text.split('|'))
    while True:
        next(dropwhile(lambda s: s != 'gb', text))
        yield next(text)
```

This gives:

```
>>> text = '>gi|124486857|ref|NP_001074751.1| inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase [Mus musculus] >gi|341941060|sp|Q6ZPR6.3|IBTK_MOUSE RecName: Full=Inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase; Short=IBtk >gi|148694536|gb|EDL26483.1| mCG128548, isoform CRA_d [Mus musculus] >gi|223460980|gb|AAI37799.1| Ibtk protein [Mus musculus]'
>>> list(extract_ids(text))
['EDL26483.1', 'AAI37799.1']
```

or you can use it in a simple loop:

```
for id in extract_ids(text):
    print id
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of work just when a simple regex would work.

Comment: @Hoopdady: Nope; I used some more text to explain how it works perhaps, but the method is all of 4 lines short. It's an alternative approach that works nice and fast otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can got without regexp, just split by '|gb|', then split the 2-nd part by '|' and take the first item:

```
s = 'the string from the question'
r = s.split('|gb|')
r.split('|')[0]
```

Of course you will have to add check if the first split return list with more/less than 2 items but I think it will be faster than using regexp.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> match_object = re.findall("\|gb\|(.*?)\|", ">gi|124486857|ref|NP_001074751.1| inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase [Mus musculus] >gi|341941060|sp|Q6ZPR6.3|IBTK_MOUSE RecName: Full=Inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase; Short=IBtk >gi|148694536|gb|EDL26483.1| mCG128548, isoform CRA_d [Mus musculus] >gi|223460980|gb|AAI37799.1| Ibtk protein [Mus musculus]")
>>> print match_object
['EDL26483.1', 'AAI37799.1']
```

The regular expression says "match any character (.), repeatedly (*), but as few as possible of them (?), and save only that group (the parentheses). They must come immediately after '|gb|' and immediately before another '|'."

I used "\|" because the "|" character denotes an alternative match in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: text = ">gi|124486857|ref|NP_001074751.1| inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase [Mus musculus] >gi|341941060|sp|Q6ZPR6.3|IBTK_MOUSE RecName: Full=Inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase; Short=IBtk >gi|148694536|gb|EDL26483.1| mCG128548, isoform CRA_d [Mus musculus] >gi|223460980|gb|AAI37799.1| Ibtk protein [Mus musculus]"

In [3]: re.findall(r'gb\|([^\|]+)', text)[0]
Out[3]: 'EDL26483.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall('gi\|([0-9]+)\|', u'''>gi|124486857|ref|NP_001074751.1| inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase [Mus musculus] >gi|341941060|sp|Q6ZPR6.3|IBTK_MOUSE RecName: Full=Inhibitor of Bruton tyrosine kinase; Short=IBtk >gi|148694536|gb|EDL26483.1| mCG128548, isoform CRA_d [Mus musculus] >gi|223460980|gb|AAI37799.1| Ibtk protein [Mus musculus]''')` works for me:
`[u'124486857', u'341941060', u'148694536', u'223460980']`

Comment: This is the wrong information; the id comes after the `gb` key, not `gi`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` is the variable which holds your string...

```
>>> import re
>>> a = ">gi|124486857|ref|NP_001074751.1| ..."
>>> re.findall(r"(?:\|gb\|)([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)(?:\|)", a)
['EDL26483.1', 'AAI37799.1']
```